# Plone sessions lasting forver

Tags: session, cookies, plone

After seeing the latest Twilight movies, I have an urge to make my Plone sessions immortal. How could I make Plone sessions which never expire and survive browser restarts?

Comment: Also I'd like to know how can I put in some werewolves into my Plone instance

Comment: Hah, I didn't even have to look to see who the author of this was :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in http://plone.org/documentation/kb/cookie-duration. Note that it is impossible to have an absolutely immortal cookie, you must set an expiration date on it or it will be removed when the browser is closed.